# Get html from a page instead of loading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that loads a page with `window.open();`

Instead of loading the page, is it possible to get the html from the page without opening it?

Comment: Welcome to [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/AJAX).

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX to download the information from the page you are trying to access?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ajax` and `jQuery`:

```
$.get( "myNewPage.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#myNewPage" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum This answer already assumed that the OP is familiar with `jQuery` because I use `jQuery.get` method which is part of `jQuery`... if he's familiar with `jQuery`, he'll easily understand that my sample code requires an HTML tag identified by `myNewPage` to be parts of the DOM.

Comment: Can you sub the myNewPage.html with a url?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with external urls that are not on the server. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Programatic If you're talking about external urls, then you'll have to be sure that the site you're trying to reach send you back the proper HTTP Header in its response as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/1905446 To sum up, if you're not the owner of this external url, this is gonna be complicated.

Comment: Maybe you'll want to use the `<iframe>` tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) is the way to go. Libraries like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) provide an easy to use way of doing this. Outside of the libraries, JavaScript has a `XMLHttpRequest` object that you can use to do this same thing.

The idea is make a request to a page, and return the markup on that page in some callback then do what you wish with that markup.

Here is an example:

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    // the ajax request is done, and the server responded with the html page
    // log the result from the ajax request
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","myPage.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**EDIT**

If you own both domains, the one making the request, and the one being requested, then you can use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). This will tell the other server to allow requests from the first domain.

If you don't own both domains, or have access to both sides, then this becomes a lot more difficult. You can either make an HTTP request from your server side, or check out [some other answers on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139725/cross-domain-request-without-cors-or-jsonp)

Comment: How could I do this with a url to a different page? I read up on xmlhttp requests and they do not support Access Across Domains

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain a little more for that. If you're accessing a different server, then things become slightly more difficult, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into AJAX-Requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Please use the jquery load method.

According to the docs,

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
> roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
> method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
> function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus
> is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the
> matched element to the returned data. This means that most uses of the
> method can be quite simple.
>
> **.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )**
>
> url Type: String; A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> data Type:
> PlainObject or String; A plain object or string that is sent to the
> server with the request.
>
> complete Type: Function( String responseText,
> String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ); A callback function that is executed
> when the request completes.

Ref: [Click Here for jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
: [Another Stack overflow question on the same lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275116/js-not-loading-correctly-on-first-pageload/30275764#30275764)

Comment: does this work with a url instead of a static webpage?

Comment: Yes. It will work with any url. You can even load google.com